# How to find number of 010 in a certain range of a binary string

Tags: string, algorithm, string-algorithm

Given a binary string. How to find occurances of **"010"** within a certain range of the string.
For example, I have the string **"0100110"** . If the given range is **3 7** ( 1 based indexing ) then the output will be **4**. I could not find any faster way to solve it.

While trying this I can solve it in **O(N)** complexity. The approach is - firstly I point out the position of all **'1'** within the certain range and using those position I will figure out the number of **'0'** in both back and forth. And then multiply number of **'0'** found in back for a single **'1'** with number of **'0'** in found in forth. Then sum up the multiplied result for each of the **'1'** within the certain range.

For the given example the position of **'1'** within the range is **{5, 6}**. Now for index **5** I have number of **'0'** in both back and forth is **2** and **1** respectively. So we can make subsequence **"010"** is **2**. Similarly for index **6** we also get the answer is **2**. In total we can make the subsequence **"010"** is **4** times in total.

But when we have a number of **Q** queries of certain ranges for a given string then my approach easily reaches into the time complexity **O(N<sup>2</sup>)**. I tried a lot but failed to find a way to optimize it. Can anybody help me with an approach that is less than **O(N<sup>2</sup>)** complexity? Just to mention the time limit should be **1 Second**. It will be a plus if you provide a pseudo code.

~Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Go through the string once and save indexes of all substrings: O(n) time and O(n) space. When you query the results it's O(1) time.

Comment: Hello @Konstantin . Could you please explain a bit more about it.

Comment: @ssavi He says about **substrings** (continuous) but you really need **subsequences**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretreatment: make auxiliary array containing cumulative number of zeros upto given position (with aux[0]=0)

```
  0 1 0 0 1 1 0  //string
0 1 1 2 3 3 3 4  //aux array A[]
```

For given `L..R` range scan for ones, for every k index of `1` get number of zeros in range - O(1) operation

```
P[k] = (A[k] - A[L-1]) * (A[R] - A[k])
S = Sum(P[k], k=L..R)
```

So we have `O(R-L)` time per query and the worst case `O(Q*N)` for Q queries

But look at formula thoroughly:

```
P[k] = (A[k] - A[L-1]) * (A[R] - A[k]) = 
       A[k] * (A[R] + A[L-1]) - A[k]^2 - A[R] * A[L-1] = 
       A[k] * LRSum - A[k]^2 - LRProd
S = Sum(A[k] for ones) * LRSum - Sum(A[k]^2) - LRProd * NumOfOnes
```

Note that `LRSum` and `LRProd` are constants for given query, and we have to calculate sums of A[k] for positions of ones and sum of squares for the same positions. Seems we can use the same idea of cumulative array and get result in `O(1)` per query.

Quick check gives `(3+3)*5 - (9+9) - 4*2 = 30-18-8 = 4` for your example.

Using cumulative arrays:

```
  0 1 0 0 1  1  0  //string
0 1 1 2 3 3  3  4  //aux array A[]
0 0 1 1 1 4  7  7  //aux array B[]
0 0 1 1 1 10 19 19  //aux array C[]

Result = (B[R] - B[L-1]) * (A[R] + A[L-1]) - (C[R] - C[L-1]) - 
                 A[R] * A[L-1] * (R - L - 1 - (A[R] - A[L-1])) = 
         (7-1) * (4 + 1) - (19 - 1) - 4 * 1 * (7 - 2  - 4 + 1) = 4
```